# ADF RichTable binding with view object

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I have created viewobject which generates columns based on a dynamic query. I want to bind the viewobjec to richtable instead of iterating through each row in viewobject and adding it to the richtable. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Drag and drop your viewobject on your page and choose for 'Table' ?

Comment: But it is not displaying columns generated from dynamic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using the dynamic table component?
Similar to this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_faces_dynamic_tags_-_for_a